# IIf query decimal removal

Tags: ms-access, decimal, iif-function

Trying to attempt the following in MS Access.

*Convert data in one field to an 18 digit number starting with 01 in another field.*

There are also some conditions that have to be met:

- the first dash should become double zeros
- the second dash should be removed
- the third and fourth dash should be a single zero
- the decimal must also be replaced with a zero

My query works fine until the decimal is the 15th character in the data.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT MasterVacant.ParcelIdNumber,
    "01" + Mid([ParcelIdNumber],1,2) + "00" + Mid([ParcelIdNumber],4,2) + Mid([ParcelIdNumber],7,1)
        + IIf(Mid([ParcelIDNumber],11,1) = "", "0"+Mid([ParcelIDNumber],9,2), Mid([ParcelIDNumber],9,3))
        + IIf(Mid([ParcelIDNumber],14,1) = ".", "0"+Mid([ParcelIDNumber],12,2), Mid([ParcelIDNumber],12,3))
        + Mid([ParcelIDNumber],15,3) AS ParcelNumber
FROM MasterVacant;
```

Here is a start and finish example...

```
'12-06-1-00-50.000-RR'  should become '011200061000050000'
'12-06-3-07-09.000-RR'  should become '011200063007009000'
'13-35-1-01-129.000-RR' should become '011300035100112900'
```

However, instead of getting `0113000351001129000' I get '013000351001129.00'.

The issue is how do I remove the decimal when the decimal is the 15th character like in the third set of example?

I receive the data as a single column. Some of it is below....

```
1. 13-35-1-07-29.000-RR 
2. 13-35-1-01-112.000-RR (Removing the decimal when the data is like this is the issue)
3. 13-35-4-01-01.000-RR
4. 13-35-4-02-04.000-RR
5. 13-35-1-13-17.000-RR
```

The output for the above data should be

```
1. 011300351007029000
2. 011300351001112000
3. 011300354001001000
4. 011300354002004000
5. 011300351013017000
```

Comment: Replace the dot by a zero and take it from there.

Comment: Is there a way I can implement and Or Mid([ParcelIdNumber],15,1)= ".","0". Would that give me an 0 if the decimal is the 15th character in the value?

Comment: But your your third example has 19 characters. And you don't list the expected results for the last five examples, and these have a comma attached. Please be very specific and double-check your examples before posting them.

Comment: Ignore the commas in the data I provided

Comment: OK. See my updated answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom function:

```vb
Public Function Make18(ByVal Value As String) As String

    Const Head  As String = "01"
    Const Tail  As String = "000"
    Const Lead  As String = "00"

    Dim Parts   As Variant
    Dim Part    As Integer
    Dim Result  As String

    Parts = Split(Split(Value, ".")(0), "-")

    For Part = LBound(Parts) To UBound(Parts)
        Select Case Part
            Case 0
                Parts(Part) = Head & Parts(Part)
            Case 1
                Parts(Part) = Lead & Parts(Part)
            Case 3, 4
                Parts(Part) = Right(Lead & Parts(Part), 3)
        End Select
    Next

    Result = Join(Parts, "") & Tail

    Make18 = Result

End Function
```

and your query becomes:

```sql
SELECT 
    MasterVacant.ParcelIdNumber,
    Make18([ParcelIdNumber]) AS ParcelNumber
FROM 
    MasterVacant;
```

Comment: This is also a good response, after running the code I am having an issue with the placement of zeros.  The first dash should be replaced by 2 zeros, the second by nothing and the remaining dashes should be replaced with one zero...Thanks

Comment: Well, we only have your sample data. If these are not representative, please correct/supplement and include the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is how I actually receive the data...  There is a ParcelIdNumber column. The data has to be converted into actual parcel numbers used by the city I am in. I will add some of the data to the original post.

Comment: Modified completely to match the current sample.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you meant the opposite where:

```
12-06-1-00-50.000-RR should become 011200061000050000 
12-06-3-07-09.000-RR should become 011200063007009000 
13-35-1-01-129.000-RR should become 0113000351001129.00
```

I would recommend the `REPLACE()` in `MSACCESS` to strip the dashes out.  Once you have the dashes out you can `MID()`

Unfortunately your attempted code does something different with the 3rd row because 3 zeros are being put in when there should be only two in my opinion.

Try in a text box:

```
=Replace("13-35-1-01-129.000-RR","-","")
```

will return `1335101129.000RR`
and see if that assists you in making your code.

Maybe go one step further and put it in a function.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. I just realized the third example is a typo. There are only two zeros when you run it. The results shown in the first two are correct. The should not be present in the final result as well. I just wish the . could be a zero. I will try the replacement function.